# La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto c#

Tags: c#

Este es un programa para mostrar varios productos a través de arreglo de objetos. Lo que sucede es que cuando estoy agregando productos con sus respectivos atributos, me aparece un error diciendo  "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto" señalando esta parte que pertenece al botón Insertar:

```
private void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        **producto.Ingresadatos(int.Parse(txtCodigo.Text), txtNombre.Text, double.Parse(txtCantidad.Text),txtUMedida.Text,double.Parse(txtCosto.Text));**
        txtCodigo.Clear(); txtNombre.Clear(); txtCantidad.Clear(); txtUMedida.Clear(); txtCosto.Clear();txtCodigo.Focus();
 }
```

Este es el código de la clase:

```
 int i, I,c1,c2,codigo;
    string nombre, unidadMe,salida;
    double costo,cantidad,cantMax,cantMin;

    Producto[] prod = new Producto[20];

    public void Ingresadatos(int cod,string nom,double cant,string uniMe,double cos)
    {

        prod[i] = new Producto();
        prod[i].codigo = cod;
        prod[i].nombre = nom;
        prod[i].cantidad = cant;
        prod[i].unidadMe = uniMe;
        prod[i].costo = cos;
    }
    public string Listar()
    {
        i++; I = i;
        for (i=0;i<I;i++)
        {
            salida+= " " + prod[i].codigo + " " + prod[i].nombre +
                " " + prod[i].cantidad +" "+ prod[i].unidadMe + " " + prod[i].costo + "\r\n";
        }
        return salida;
    }
```

Comment: De verdad codificas asi? con varias instrucciones por línea? con varias declaraciones por línea? espero que no.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente sea alguna de las 2 variables a las cuales le estas realizando el Parse, prueba a utilizar un Try Parse en vez de un Parse y comparte la salida, con este código se intentara Parsear y en caso contrario pondremos el valor a 0, asi sabremos que variable en concreto te esta dando el error, saludos

```
int valor = 0;

int.TryParse(unacarga.tbCarga.Text, out valor );

datos[i] = valor;
```